# Cannot access variable inside inner class without making it Final

Tags: java, android

The code asks the user if they want to delete the entry from the recyclerview / mysql database. The functionality works, however if the user selects no the item is still getting deleted from the recycler-view (temporarily) until the screen is refreshed then it comes back. I tried moving the removeItem(position) method into the yes/no method. However it states the variable must be made final. If I make it final it breaks the functionality. How can I arrange this code in a way where when the user clicks no the viewholder isnt removed?

```
 /**
 * Method which removes a row from the recycler-view view-holder. Also captured the cbtId Primary Key which is sent
  * via Retrofit to the server to ensure the correct row is deleted from the database.
 * @param position
 */
public void removeItem(int position) {
    cbtId = mWorkoutLogList.get(position).getCbtId();
    mWorkoutLogList.remove(position);
    mWorkoutLogAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
}


/**
 * On click method which calls the deleteLog() method to delete the row from the recycler view.
 * @param position
 */
@Override
public void onDeleteClick(int position) {

    deleteLog(position);

}


/**
 * Method which uses Retrofit to send a call to the MYSQL server to delete a workout log.
 */
private void deleteLog(int position){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Are you Sure?");
    builder.setMessage("Deleted Workout Logs cannot be restored.");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Call<WorkoutLogList> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().deleteLog(cbtId);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<WorkoutLogList>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<WorkoutLogList> call, Response<WorkoutLogList> response) {
                    removeItem(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<WorkoutLogList> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
    ad.show();

}
```

Comment: In what sense does making 'position' final break the functionality?  I see no assignments to it.  At an abstract level, it seems clear that after you've initiated the removal of an object that is identified by its position then we're still talking about the same unchanged position until removal is complete.  So if position doesn't need to change, why can't it be 'final'?

Comment: When I make position final and move the method you're right in that it fixes the problem where the recycler-view row doesnt get removed anymore when the user selects no. However if they select yes the row gets removed but it doesnt get removed from the database so when you refresh the screen the row repopulates in the recycler view

Answer (score 0):

Making the position variable final and moving it to the correct location fixed the issue.

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        removeItem(position);
        Call<WorkoutLogList> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().deleteLog(cbtId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<WorkoutLogList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<WorkoutLogList> call, Response<WorkoutLogList> response) {

            }
```

The removeItem(posiiton) method needed to be placed just befor the retrofit database call as this method gets the cbtId, without that id the row could not be removed from the database.